# I want to limit the maximum display length 5 items for each list (VueJS)

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

Example : in Udemy filter option when you click in See More button it show only 5 items.

I create the same option using Vue but when i clicked to See more it show me all the list I want to limit this list to 5 items for each click.

This is my whole code :

```
    <template>
  <div class="modal fade" id="FilterPanelModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="FilterPanelModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body pb-0">
          <form>
              <div class="row mb-xl-0 mb-lg-0 mb-3">

              <fieldset v-bind:name="FilterByTopic.FilterByTopic_Name" 
                        class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <legend class="filter-title"> 
                      <i class="fas fa-folder mr-1"></i> {{ FilterByTopic.FilterByTopic_Title }}
                  </legend>
                  <div v-for="(Topic, Index) in FilterByTopic.FilterByTopicOptions" 
                       v-bind:key="Topic.id"
                       class="filter-option-cnt">
                  <div v-if="Index < FilterByTopic_limit_by" 
                       class="filter-option">
                  <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                  <input type="checkbox" 
                         class="custom-control-input"
                         name="Filter-ByTopic"
                         v-model="FilterByTopic.FilterByT"
                         v-bind:id="Topic.Topic_UID"
                         :value="Topic.Topic_UID"
                         readonly />
                  <label class="custom-control-label" :for="Topic.Topic_UID">
                      {{ Topic.Topic_Name }} <small class="text-muted">{{ Topic.Topic_Count }}</small>
                  </label>
                  </div><!-- End custom-control -->
                  </div><!-- End filter-option -->
                  </div><!-- End filter-option-cnt -->
                  <button v-on:click="FilterByTopic_MoreAndLess(FilterByTopic_default_limit, FilterByTopic.FilterByTopicOptions.length)" 
                          type="button"
                          class="btn btn-link pl-0">
                          <span v-if="FilterByTopic_limit_by === 5">
                              <i class="fas fa-plus mr-1"></i>
                          </span>
                          <span v-else>
                              <i class="fas fa-minus mr-1"></i>
                          </span>
                          {{ FilterByTopic_limit_by === 5 ? "See More" : "See Less" }}
                  </button>
              </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

              <fieldset v-bind:name="FilterBySubCategory.FilterBySubCategory_Name" 
                        class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <legend class="filter-title">
                      <i class="fas fa-tags mr-1"></i> {{ FilterBySubCategory.FilterBySubCategory_Title }}
                  </legend>
                  <div class="filter-option-cnt">

                  </div><!-- End filter-option-cnt -->
              </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

              <fieldset v-bind:name="FilterByLevel.FilterByLevel_Name" 
                        class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <legend class="filter-title"><i class="fas fa-level-up-alt mr-1"></i> {{ FilterByLevel.FilterByLevel_Title }}</legend>

              </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

              <fieldset v-bind:name="FilterByLanguage.FilterByLanguage_Name" 
                        class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <legend class="filter-title"><i class="fas fa-language mr-1"></i> {{ FilterByLanguage.FilterByLanguage_Title }}</legend>
              </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

              </div><!-- End row -->

              <div class="row">

              <fieldset class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <legend class="filter-title"><i class="far fa-money-bill-alt mr-1"></i> Price</legend>
              </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->
              <fieldset class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <legend class="filter-title"><i class="far fa-lightbulb mr-1"></i> Features</legend>
              </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->
              <fieldset class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <legend class="filter-title"><i class="fas fa-star mr-1"></i> Ratings</legend>
              </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->
              <fieldset class="filter-content col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12">
                  <legend class="filter-title"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt mr-1"></i> Duration</legend>
              </fieldset><!-- End col-xl-3 col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 -->

              </div><!-- End row -->
          </form>
      </div><!-- End modal-body -->
      </div><!-- End modal-content -->
      </div><!-- End modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- End FilterPanelModal -->
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: 'FilterPanelModal',
    data: function() {
        return {
            // For Filter By Topic
            FilterByTopic_default_limit: 5,
            FilterByTopic_limit_by: 5,
            FilterByTopic: {
                FilterByTopic_Title: "Topic",
                FilterByTopic_Name: "Topic",
                FilterByT: [],
                FilterByTopicOptions: [
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 0, 
                        Topic_UID: "JXETdWWM",
                        Topic_Name: "Ionic",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 1, 
                        Topic_UID: "g2K8SkFA",
                        Topic_Name: "PHP",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 2, 
                        Topic_UID: "P1Q6HOFN",
                        Topic_Name: "Python",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 3, 
                        Topic_UID: "rMzXsrwO",
                        Topic_Name: "Ruby & Rails",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 4, 
                        Topic_UID: "IaMfmedm",
                        Topic_Name: ".NET / C#",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 5, 
                        Topic_UID: "kAqpieja",
                        Topic_Name: "Java",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 6, 
                        Topic_UID: "rUf0AGyV",
                        Topic_Name: "Perl",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 7, 
                        Topic_UID: "znaJ4diW",
                        Topic_Name: "ColdFusion",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 8, 
                        Topic_UID: "uXmoqYpc",
                        Topic_Name: "JavaScript",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 9, 
                        Topic_UID: "daL54tCv",
                        Topic_Name: "ActionScript",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 10, 
                        Topic_UID: "GiXDC0oe",
                        Topic_Name: "Angular",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 11, 
                        Topic_UID: "AvNhruTX",
                        Topic_Name: "C++",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 12, 
                        Topic_UID: "tUxVxhHH",
                        Topic_Name: "SQL",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 13, 
                        Topic_UID: "kfvzVRsH",
                        Topic_Name: "MySQL",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 14, 
                        Topic_UID: "wSeLABXD",
                        Topic_Name: "MongoDB",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 15, 
                        Topic_UID: "SuqxZbEM",
                        Topic_Name: "Dart",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 16, 
                        Topic_UID: "BwAXbUmp",
                        Topic_Name: "Haskell",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 17, 
                        Topic_UID: "cHSjfDKs",
                        Topic_Name: "Kotlin",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 18, 
                        Topic_UID: "PEpWCdtF",
                        Topic_Name: "Ruby",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 19, 
                        Topic_UID: "RWMKGkCj",
                        Topic_Name: "NodeJS",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    },
                    { 
                        Topic_id: 20, 
                        Topic_UID: "NqHzgDWS",
                        Topic_Name: "Wordpress",
                        Topic_Count: "(0)"
                    }
                ]
            }, // End Filter By Topic

            // For Filter By SubCategory
            FilterBySubCategory: {
                FilterBySubCategory_Title: "Subcategory",
                FilterBySubCategory_Name: "Subcategory",
                FilterBySubCat: [],
                FilterBySubCategoryOptions: []
            },
            // End Filter By SubCategory

            // For Filter By Level
            FilterByLevel: {
                FilterByLevel_Title: "Level",
                FilterByLevel_Name: "Level",
                FilterByLv: [],
                FilterByLevelOptions: []
            },
            // End Filter By Level

            // For Filter By Language
            FilterByLanguage: {
                FilterByLanguage_Title: "Language",
                FilterByLanguage_Name: "Language",
                FilterByLang: [],
                FilterByLanguageOptions: []
            }
            // End Filter By Language

        }
    },
    computed: {

    },
    methods: {
        FilterByTopic_MoreAndLess (FilterByTopic_default_limit, filters_length) {
            this.FilterByTopic_limit_by = (this.FilterByTopic_limit_by === FilterByTopic_default_limit) ? filters_length : FilterByTopic_default_limit;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to do something like this:

```
<div v-for="(Topic, Index) in FilterByTopic.FilterByTopicOptions.slice(0, (numberOfClick + 1) * 5)" 
                       v-bind:key="Topic.id"
                       class="filter-option-cnt">
```

...

```
data: function() {
        return {
            numberOfClick: 0,
...

methods: {
    FilterByTopic_MoreAndLess (FilterByTopic_default_limit, filters_length) {
        this.FilterByTopic_limit_by = (this.FilterByTopic_limit_by === FilterByTopic_default_limit) ? filters_length : FilterByTopic_default_limit;

        this.numberOfClick ++;
    }
}
```

After each click you can increment your `numberOfClick` by 1.

Comment: Can you rewrite the same code based on your Idea please

Comment: @HoussamHammouda, check updates. And replace it in your code.

Comment: it work for me bro but after click show 5 items but I still have more items the problem is I want to show auther items until finished

Comment: @HoussamHammouda, can you be more specific?

Comment: see this image bro https://imgur.com/a/MGkL6g6 it should be See More not See Less / See Less should showing until the end of the list